# Can't get paramaters from url page of content

Tags: plugins, nginx

I'm build two plugins, each install on a different site. Plugin Site "A" for encryption all link on content of post, If I have some links look like :

```
<a href="facebook.com">Go to facebook now</a>
```

It will be encrypt to like this

```
<a href="siteb.crot/2015/10/title-of-post/?link=asdasdasd">Got to facebook now</a>
```

So on site "B" I want to get `link` paramter, I have finished that and **on local works perfectly**, `link` paramater can get from url, and decrypt it. **My problem is on production (nginx)**, I can't get `link` parameter.

```
 // wp-content/plugins/my-plugins/class.safelink.php
<?php
Class Safelink {
    public static function init(){
        add_filter('the_content', Array('Safelink','insert_content_here'));
    }

    public static function insert_content_here ($content) {
        if ( is_single()  && filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'link') ) {
            $params_code = absint(filter_input(INPUT_GET, link''));
            $dnc_url = self::decrypt($params_code);
            $custom_content = '<div style="text-align:center" id="aDivSafeLink"><a href="'.$dnc_url.'">Download Here</a></div>';
            $custom_content .= $content;
            return $custom_content;
        } else {
            return $content;
        }
    }

    public static function decrypt($params_code){
        $key = 'mykey';
        $encrypted = strtr($params_code, '-_,', '+/=');
        $data = base64_decode($encrypted);
        $vi = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
        return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $vi));
    }
}
?>
```

I try with `$_GET['link']` but output is null, just only appear like this :

```
<div style="text-align:center" id="aDivSafeLink"><a>Download Here</a></div>
```

And also, I tried with

```
add_filter('query_vars', Array('Safelink', 'parameter_queryvars'));

public static function parameter_queryvars( $qvars )
{
        $qvars[] = 'link';
        return $qvars;
}
```

But still null when I print `$wp_query->query_vars['link'];`

FYI, I'm use nginx and subdirectory (subdomain). On apache server I can get `link` parameter.

Comment: If you do `print_r($_GET);` as the very first thing in `insert_content_here` do you see the 'link' parameter in the array?

Comment: @phatskat I can't see `link` parameter in the array, `$_GET` or `$wp_query->query_vars`, Actually I have tried with another site (fresh install), the plugin works perfectly, I can get a `link`, I'm confuse why "`site B`" can't push a new `query_vars` or I can't get another parameter from url.